# Cannot resolve symbol of my class Android-Studio

Tags: java, android, oop, android-studio

I'm having this issue where I'm getting an error that states, "cannot resolve symbol". 
These words below are red(Included in code below):

```
HttpEntity

HttpResponse

ClientProtocolException

HttpPost

DefaultHttpClient
```

I've already tried:

1. Build > Clean Project
2. Build > Rebuild Project
3. File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart
4. Close Android-Studio and restart my MacBook.
5. Sync Project with Grade Files.

None of these worked & these are the suggestions I've tried which is what I've been coming across in Google searches.

My `mainActivity.java` class is fine but my `appMaking.java` class is throwing me this error.

Thanks for reading.

appMaking.java

```
package com.apress.gerber.currencies;
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class appMaking {

}
```

Comment: What is your target API ?

Comment: @swbradshaw I'm not sure.  Where can I find this out?

Comment: You have added the libraries for [httpcore](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore) and [httpclient](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient), correct?

Comment: Look at build.gradle file for your app.  You'll find compileSdkVersion listed near the top.

Comment: @MattClark I've only written what's on my original post when it comes to `httpcore` and `httpclient` so I guess I haven't added the libraries for them.  How do I do so?

Comment: @swbradshaw Oh ok, I see it.  It says `compileSdkVersion 25`.

Answer (score 1):

Android 6 (API 23) [removed the Apache HTTP Library](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client).

You can still reference it by adding the following to your build.gradle file:

```
android {
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Comment: I've added your code to my build.grade file, the red is gone from the import statements (now it's saying it's unused) but now when I declare objects, i.e. `static inputStream s = null`
The `inputStream` is red.

Comment: inputStream is not a class.  Try InputStream instead, make sure to include java.io.InputStream at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because of the fact that you do not have apache `httpclient` in your library path.

According to [this page](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html), you should be able to get this working by adding the following to your gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
}
```

*edit*

According to the link provided by `swbradshaw`, you should try and avoid using httpcomponenets in new code, and use the libraries provided to you instead.

i.e., [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/1790644) for more usage details.

Comment: I've added your code to my build.grade file, the red is gone from the import statements (now it's saying it's unused) but now when I declare objects, i.e. `static inputStream s = null`
The `inputStream` is red.

Comment: [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), capital I.

Comment: ahh nice catch :) But it's still giving me the red error :(